# Unexplained deletion of emails by Mail

Tags: macos, ios, mail.app, email

I was notified of user side deletion of more than 50 emails by my provider on March 1st. I was asked to look into it but didn't think nothing of it since I did not notice any lost emails. I use IMAP to fetch my email with Mail on Mac and iPhone. Today I was looking for an email in my "sent" folder and noticed that the oldest email in there is from February 23rd. I'm shocked. My account is not compromised. I have no clue what could've caused the deletion of those emails. I'm on the fence of stopping to use Apple Mail. The only explanation I have which was pointed out as a possibility by my provider is a failed update of external email software in this case Apple Mail which of course would be unacceptable. In all my years of using Thunderbird on Linux this has never happened to me.

*From Comment (below)*
the provider notified me that it detected deletion of more than 50 emails and asked me to make sure it hadn't happened by mistake. I cannot post the text as it is in German. I wouldn't say I have lots of large attachments. Also my iCloud is far from being maxed out

Comment: Do you have lots of attachments? like videos, pictures etc? they take up storage space. Have you checked how much storage you use on the server? What was the detail in the mail about "batch deletion"?

Comment: It is unclear in your question... You mention your email provider will be batch deleting a bunch of emails and then say that a bunch of messages are "missing." Is there a reason you believe your email provider was not responsible? Mail.app has been rock solid for me for *years* I would be more likely to think that emails were "cleaned up" from your sent mail folder by your email provider than jump to the conclusion that mail.app did something wrong.

Comment: @SteveChambers Sorry for being unclear: the provider notified me that it detected deletion of more than 50 emails and asked me to make sure it hadn't happened by mistake. I cannot post the text as it is in German. I wouldn't say I have lots of large attachments. Also my iCloud is far from being maxed out.

Comment: Your *provider* notified you of a mail deletion of 50 emails?  This is a red flag for me as it’s abnormal for an email host to monitor your mailbox in this manner.  Mailbox *size* is is often monitored to ensure continuity of service, but not mailbox content.  Are you certain this came from your mail provider?

Comment: If you *need* those emails I would ask your provider if they can restore them from a backup. I have no other thoughts other than the slip of a finger/mouse that accidentally deleted those emails. Like I said before mail.app is *unlikely* to be the culprit. If you rebuild the mailboxes `Mail > Mailbox > Rebuild` that should clean things up and might (depending on what is going on) fix any issues with Sent Mail that might be causing messages to go missing.

Comment: @SteveChambers Rebuild didn't do anything. My provider sent me a backup. They are very privacy focused and get recomended often for that reason (Posteo). I don't know if they can actually tell the number of emails. The size of the backups yes. They told me that they've been contacted by more than a few Apple Mail users (MacOS and iOS) that sent emails were lost after an update. THAT is one big red flag :P

Comment: Well the rebuild is one of those things that can't hurt as it only rebuilds the index, glad you got a backup.